# WIX Toolset - Custom Action command doesn't correctly detect Windows 10 version

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installshield, wix3.8

I have an installer that deploys and runs a separate `.exe` file to deploy drivers to a system. Unfortunately, Microsoft seems to have dropped support for the `VersionNT` macro in Windows 10 and onward, [so I implemented an approach suggested in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31991006/1022889): write a function to query `kernel32.dll` for its version number, and compare against a sentinel value (`10.0.10240.16384`).

Here's the catch: when I run this command directly from an Administrative Console, the command correctly detects the version of Windows I'm running.

```
Current Windows Version: 10.0.10240.16384 - Cutoff Version: 10.0.10240.16384
```

However, when the command is executed as a Custom Action from my WIX Toolset installer, it seems to think I'm using an older version of Windows. My best guess at this point is the installer or the Custom Action command running in some sort of automatic compatibility mode.

```
Current Windows Version: 6.2.10240.16384 - Cutoff Version: 10.0.10240.16384
```

How can I proceed? The `VersionNT` abandonment is frustrating as it is, with the new version API (ie: `IsWindows10OrGreater()`) only available on Win10 or later, so on older machines I have to `dlopen/dlsym` and test for failures. I don't know why it's so hard to create a simple `int return_OS_Version(major, minor, release, revision,)` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack (they do this, we do that...) but desperate times call for desperate measures....

In all of the compatibility games MSFT is playing they only seem to be masking the Major and Minor but Build and revision.  I've also worked out that on Win8 they mask it as 6.2 and on Win 10 they mask it as 6.3.   So therefore I feel comfortable doing this:

```
<Property Id="WIN10FOUND">
  <DirectorySearch Id="searchSystem" Path="[SystemFolder]" Depth="0">
    <FileSearch Id="searchFile" Name="advapi32.dll" MinVersion="6.3.10000.0"/>
  </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

Comment: Quick question: Why go with `advapi32.dll` over `kernel32.dll` or some other file? Thanks!

Comment: [Thank you. This was a helpful solution.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932646/versionnt-msi-property-on-windows-10?lq=1)

Comment: I went with advapi32.dl because I didn't find kernel32.dll in c:\windows\syswos64.  A 32bit MSI running on a 64bit Windows wouldn't find it.  Or atleast that's what I'm pretty sure I saw on one of my VMs.  On this laptop I see it.  Hmmmmmmm  I'm getting old and senile.

Answer (score 5):

It is also possible to detect Windows 10 using RegistrySearch. For instance the node HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion contains the CurrentBuild and CurrentBuildNumber values. For Windows 8.1 or Windows Server 2012R2 these values are 9600 and for Windows 10 they will most probably be 14393.

```
<Property Id="WINDOWSBUILDNUM" Secure="yes">
  <RegistrySearch Id="YOUR_ID_HERE" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" Name="CurrentBuild" Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

Having got a value one can handle it like this, in order to install a specific for Windows 10 file:

```
<Component Id="YOUR_ID_HERE" Guid="YOUR_GUID_HERE" DiskId="1">
    <Condition><![CDATA[Installed OR (WINDOWSBUILDNUM > 9999)]]></Condition>
    <File Id="YOUR_ID_HERE" Name="Api.dll" Source="$(var.SolutionDir)\TheRestOfThePath\Api_for_win_10.dll"/>        
</Component>
```

Comment: This key seems now to be the only reliable way to distinguish between versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach could be detecting a correct Windows version programmatically in a custom action and setting a property. The property can be checked in a condition.

```cs
private static bool IsWindows10OrGreater()
{
    Version ver = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
    return ver.Major >= 10;
}

[CustomAction]
public static ActionResult SetWindowsVersion(Session session)
{
    Version ver = Environment.OSVersion.Version;
    session["OS_VERSION"] = ver.ToString();
    // make Windows 10 as a default in case setting this property fails for some reason
    session["IS_LESS_THAN_WIN10"] = !IsWindows10OrGreater() ? "1" : null;
    return ActionResult.Success;
}
```