# VersionNT64 and WindowsBuild have the same values on Server 2016, 2019 and 2022

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

My end goal is to allow installation only on Server 2016, 2019 and 2022. I've opted to use `VersionNT64` and `WindowsBuild` in `<Condition>`, however they seem to always be set to `603` and `9600` (respectively) regardless of what OS I'm running the msi on.

On the left the installation log generated by executing the msi with `/l*vx` and on the right `winver`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The GetVersionEx function lies. Which process is setting those properties? Does it have a supported OS guid for Win10 in its manifest?

Comment: @Anders 1. According to the docs the installer itself sets these values, however I'm not sure why it sets it to the *wrong* values. 2. Not sure what you mean by "supported OS guid for Win10 in its manifest". At the moment I don't have any reference to any OS in the `*.wsx` file.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the application manifest inside .exe files. Windows lies about the version by design unless the .exe opts in to Windows 10 support. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#supportedOS

Comment: @Anders I see, thanks. Do you have any resources? Anyway I'm not dealing with exe files, I'm generating an msi file from a wsx file

Comment: I manually created a manifest file, but still not sure how to tell wix to embed/connect it to the generated msi file

Comment: I don't think you can manually add the manifest if it is the MSI service doing the call to GetVersion. Do you have a plain .msi file or a exe bootstrapper?

Comment: @Anders Plain msi

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932646/versionnt-msi-property-on-windows-10/31991006#31991006 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33817452/wix-toolset-custom-action-command-doesnt-correctly-detect-windows-10-version

Comment: Broken by design I guess https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/versionnt-value-for-windows-10-server

Comment: @Anders jeez... thanks. Ended up reading the registry

Comment: I wrote up an "answer" [on the (origin of the) issues with Windows 10 version checking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49343826/129130) quite some time ago. I haven't reviewed it since, but maybe have a quick look?